# Smartgit authenticate fails for bitbucket repo

Tags: git, bitbucket, smartgit

I am trying to add a remote repository to smartgit. It fails to authenticate. I am in smartgit selecting **remote>add**, then adding the url provided by bitbucket on the repository page. I then press add and type in my password ( which I have checked by logging out and back in to bitbucket). It then gives a dialog saying that authentication has failed. I can't see what I could be doing wrong. I have done this a good few times and it always works. Is there anything that I'm doing wrong here; or that has changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a bit old, but I had the same error with a public repository I wanted to push to, I had cloned it with a raw url

```
https://bitbucket.org/myuser/myrepo
```

to fix I appended the username I wanted

```
https://user@bitbucket.org/myuser/myrepo
```

Comment: yea I think I worked out something along those lines but I can't remember - haven't time to test this but I'll tick the answer anyway - sounds right to me - thanks